# Run scripts remotely and securely

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, automation

I'm looking for a way that normal users can do remote changes on a linux box through a web interface. Say for example update the dns settings for their domain. The script needs to run under root. I have three questions.

Firstly, is the correct way to do this via SSH, with a user that you set to only have root access to the scripts. Using visudo?

Secondly, is there perhaps a better way to implement this? I'm thinking if the web interface server where i would store the auth key gets compromised. Though the attack surface would be rather limited due to the restrictions done in visudo?

Lastly, this would be run quite frequently, could that cause any issues?

Edited for clarify the purpose.

Comment: Why would you want to use anything other than SSH for this? SSH is the de facto standard, it can be easily well secured, and it's easy to get support on. None of which are true for a web interface.

Comment: Maybe i was unclear. The web interface is to be used by normal users to say for example change a dns setting for their domain. So the web interface does remote changes through SSH, that was the plan at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like Cpanel or some such alternative.  Check out this StackOverflow question for a few ideas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562388/free-cpanel-alternative